# Microsoft Identity Confirmation Email with gmail smtp

Tags: c#, webforms, smtp, gmail

This appears to baffle my mind, I have set up Identity 2.0 on a legacy application with our institution's email which is on google suite (work space).
So we decided to use gmail smtp for the email, (enabling less secure apps) on google for the email address we need to send with.

I noticed 2-factor Auth emails are sent correctly but all emails that contain Identity `callbackCode` were not being sent. Gmail was sending a mail to the sender email that the email was rejected.

We changed the approach, removed links and just decided to send the link for the user to copy and paste it in browser.
Now Forgot Password works, email confirmation email doesn't send in production and there's nothing in the email inbox or outbox to determine what the error is. It sends email confirmation email every time in dev environment.

Think may be more related to gmail than to the code so I have not added any code here.
Any pointers why that is and how do we even start debugging to see what is actually happening.

```
private async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string name = null)
{
    var toName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? email : name;
    var messageBody = new MimeMessage();
    messageBody.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_app, _emailSettings.EmailAddress));
    messageBody.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(toName, email));
    messageBody.Subject = subject;
    var messType = StringUtils.ContainsHTMLElements(message) ? "html" : "plain";
    messageBody.Body = new TextPart(messType)
    {
        Text = message
    };
    await SendAsync(messageBody);
    return true;
}
```

This is the sendAsync

```
private async Task SendAsync(MimeMessage messageBody)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync("sendemail@institution.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                
        await client.AuthenticateAsync("sendemail@institution.com", "password");

        await client.SendAsync(messageBody);
        await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot the question part of your question.   What is the issue exactly, can I see your code?

Comment: Email confirmation not sent and no error in production. How to debug that. All other emails are sent including Forgot password that also contain `callbackUrl` with code

Comment: Code added to the question. Don't believe there is a problem with the code because it send all other emails apart from Email Confirmation mail

Comment: You may not think its a problem with your code but you should always add a [example] to your question so that we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code from my sample.  I think you forgot the smtp server, and try using `NetworkCredential` and make sure you are sending an `AppsPassword` and not the actual gmail user password.

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(From , GoogleAppPassword),
            EnableSsl = true,
        };
var mailMessage = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(From),
            Subject = Subject,
            Body = Body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
        };
mailMessage.To.Add(To);

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

## Xoauth with workspace service account.

```
var userEmail = "support@daimto.com"

const string PathToServiceAccountKeyFile = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\workspaceserviceaccount.json";

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
    .CreateWithUser(userEmail)  // delegate to user on workspace.
    .CreateScoped(new[] {"https://mail.google.com/"});

var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    From = userEmail,
    To = to,
    MessageText = "This is a test message using https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol",
    Subject = "Testing GmailSMTP with XOauth2"
};

try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        
        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (message.From, credential.Token.AccessToken);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2, CancellationToken.None);
        
        client.Send(message.GetMessage());
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


public class EmailMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }

    public MimeMessage GetMessage()
    {
        var body = MessageText;
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("From a user", From));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("To a user", To));
        message.Subject = Subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, `AppsPassword` is not allowed for google workspace emails. That's what I read and I also couldn't generate an `AppPassword` for the email in question. Let me know if there's anything else I can do. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered a service account and using xoauth instead.   In which case using the Gmail API would probably be easier

Comment: I was trying the xoauth but it wasn't very clear to me. Is there anything that I can be pointed to especially with it's setup

Comment: Try my edit let me know if you have any issues.